# Refresh issue on angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, refresh

We are working on a web app using angular 8. When we are on the page of a certain component and we press ctrl+f5 or refresh from browser, we get white page and this list of error:
[image]

from the "unchaught syntaxError: unexpected token '<' " we understood that the browser is trying to load a script but gets a .html file insted. The problem is that inside our index.html file, every single script is commented and there is no "scripts.js". How can i solve/what is the possible problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using use hash routing configuration

```js
routerModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

Angular will start handling the redirections himself, instead of deffering it to the server.

Right now your issue is that the server has to handle the redirections, and tons of different errors can happen when it's not set up properly.

Comment: we already has that exactly line of code, the redirect/refresh on other page works fine, but on this specific component page it doesn't work

Comment: What's the difference between this component and the other ones ?

Comment: jk, i was remembering we had the same line of code, but useHash was set on false. I'm sorry! Anyway, now it works, but in the page's url i have something like my domain/#/component. Is there a way to not show "#" ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that's what the hash does. Don't worry, it's a W3C standard though. If your only concern is about the look of your URL, then I'm sorry you won't be able to do much !

Comment: The other solution is to setup your server to handle redirections, but it's not angular-related, you'd get better luck asking with tags related to your server ([tag:nodejs], [tag:nginx] maybe ?)